# Which font package in Linux supports small hyphen minus font

Tags: linux

I wanted to know which font package in Linux supports "small hyphen minus" font.
I tried searching all around but unable to find a suitable font package for it.

Comment: what is *small hyphen minus*?

Comment: As in `Unicode Character 'SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+FE63)`? I would have thought most of them. It's available in arial, courier new & noto sans. If you are running KDE, then run `kcharselect` and search for `small hyphen minus` and choose a font.

Comment: You can use Windows TTC fonts in Linux.